# How to remove iframe when have a post id in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a simple code:

```
function filter_widgets($content) {
   global $post;
   if($post->ID = 1210) {
       $content = preg_replace('/<p>\s*(<iframe .*>*.<\/iframe>)\s*<\/p>/iU', '', $content);
   }
   return $content; 
}
add_filter('the_content', 'filter_widgets');
```

But when run postId=1210 is result can't iframe, how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$content = preg_replace("/(<iframe[^<]+<\/iframe>)/", '', $content);
```